# Feedback form inside a dialogbox causing error when back button is pressed again android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, removechild

I am trying to make a feedback form in dialog box.

When I press a back button of android it disappears as normal, but when I press it again it gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I've searched a lot, tried several methods of calling `removeView()` and many others - but none worked.

Comment: If you are inflating contents of dialog, While inflating the contents:  use **false**  `inflate(R.layout.some,SomeParentView,false)`.

Comment: @wingman: it still throws the same exception!!! thnx by d way..plz cn i hv some other way it will be of great help.

Comment: Next thing you can try is, not assigning a parent in inflate : `inflate(R.layout.some,null,false)` .

Comment: @wingman: this doesn't solve the problem even. thnx a lot for the try!